# Excel - refresh data on specific time using VBscript

Tags: excel, time, refresh

Hy all.
I need some help. I will be very grateful for any help. 
I don't know about using VBscript in excel.

I am using excel 2016. I have a workbook which has connections to MySQL for query. I want that the data connections in work book may be refreshed at specific time intervals.

I try this code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("13:55:00"), "MyMacro"
End Sub


Sub MyMacro()
 ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
```

The workbook is opened but don't refresh data. 
Can some one please guide me for adding or editing code for this purpose.

Comment: Where do you place your codes?

Comment: The first part Workbook_Open i put in ThisWorkbook, and for second MyMacro i created Module1

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Application.OnTime_en.html

Try

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("13:55:00"), "Module1.MyMacro"
End Sub
```